Pandas - get subset of frames as a reference to modify
I need to get a subset of records from a bunch of records, and this works fine to get the records I need:
sub_set = record_set.loc[record_set['Serial_Nbr'] == someSerialNumber]
However, it looks like sub_set is a copy of the matching data, rather than a reference. I need to actually modfiy the found records (set a particular column value to something else).
How do I get sub_set as a reference that I can change in the original set of data frames?

You can't do this. At least not reliably.
I would rather recommend to save the boolean mask and reuse it where you need it.
For example:
mask = record_set['Serial_Nbr'] == someSerialNumber

sub_set = record_set.loc[mask]

# do something with sub_set (that doesn't change its shape)
# then

record_set.loc[mask] = sub_set

Alternatively, and assuming your index has unique indices, work on sub_set and update the original DataFrame:
sub_set = record_set.loc[record_set['Serial_Nbr'] == someSerialNumber]

# do something with sub_set

# update the original
record_set.update(sub_set)


What's the df.loc in your first example, should that be record_set or what?

Yes, that's a typo ;)
